# Error Importing existing resources into Terraform State File

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to refactor some of my modules, which requires me to move existing resources into a different state file.

Normally importing resources is monotonous but straightforward.

I do not know how to interpret the following ***"The number of path segments is not divisible by 2"*** error when attempting to import any of these resources.

This is happening on all resources I am attempting to import (which I have successfully done many times in the past)

```
CLI> terraform import azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm /resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01

Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm: Importing from ID "/resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01"...
azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm: Import complete!

  Imported azurerm_virtual_machine (ID: /resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01)
azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm: Refreshing state... (ID: /resource/subscriptions/XXX...soft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01)

Error: azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm (import id: /resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01): 1 error(s) occurred:

* import azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm result: /resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01: azurerm_virtual_machine.east_mm01_vm: The number of path segments is not divisible by 2 in "resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01"
```

Terraform Version:

```
CLI> terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.azurerm v1.20.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your resource ID is wrong (`/resource/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01`). it should be this:

```
/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stguemm01
```

Comment: weird, could swear I tried that.  You, sir (or madam), are my hero.  that was the issue!

Comment: I'm having the same issue and my line reads `The number of path segments is not divisible by 2 in "subscriptions/xxx.....` .   So, this answer does not really help me.  I don't know how I could change it to `/subscriptions...`. v2.93.0 terraform

Comment: create a new question then

Comment: I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808969/terraform-apply-error-the-number-of-path-segments-is-not-divisible-by-2-azure    I might also bounty it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such an issue when trying to import an SSH key into a Terraform module.

I had the error below:

```
module.ssh_public_key.azurerm_ssh_public_key.main: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/group1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/SshPublicKeys/mySshPublicKeyName1"...

Error: parsing Resource ID "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/group1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/SshPublicKeys/mySshPublicKeyName1": ID was missing the `sshPublicKeys` element
```

[Terraform Azure documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/ssh_public_key) specified to use this:

```
terraform import azurerm_ssh_public_key.example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/group1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/SshPublicKeys/mySshPublicKeyName1
```

However, there is a typo error with the `SshPublicKeys`. The first `S` should be **lowercase** and not **uppercase**, that is, `sshPublicKeys` and not `SshPublicKeys`

So we will have:

```
terraform import azurerm_ssh_public_key.example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/group1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys/mySshPublicKeyName1
```